# How to implement Spring LDAP authentication when application deployed in JBoss on unix environment?

Tags: java, spring, unix, jboss, spring-ldap

I am trying to implement LDAP authentication using spring security and jboss server.

Below is my environment setup:

1. Active directory running on company Windows server
2. application to be deployed jboss server running on RHEL 6.4
3. java version to be used: 1.6
4. JBoss version: jboss-eap6, jboss-as-7.1.1 Final

What i am trying to achieve is :

1. When the user open the application url from the windows machine in company network, he should get authenticated against the company LDAP server and be able to go the dashboard with being asked for password.
2. When the same url is opened from any machine outside company network, the the login page should be displayed and on providing credentials authentication should be done against the company LDAP and then the user specific dashboard page should be displayed.

I have already gone through the WAFFLE and SPNEGO documentation/tutorials available over internet, but WAFFLE dont work in OS other than Windows as it uses some Win32 api. Also What SPNEGO (PRE-AUTH) does is not exactly what i want to achieve.

In short in want to implemnent what WAFFLE do but the problem is that my application would be deployed in unix machine.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is start out configuring your application using an in-memory authentication provider.
[Internalisation using Spring Security In-Memory Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226183/internalisation-using-spring-security-in-memory-authentication)

The only thing you then have to do is change out the in-memory authentication provider with an LDAP authentication provider.
The best information I found so far is in the spring reference itself.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html

1. Add the Ldap active directory address

   < ldap-server url="ldap://springframework.org:389/dc=springframework,dc=org" />
2. Hook up the ldap bind authentication provider

   < ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
         user-search-base="ou=people"/>

Comment: i have already implemented the normal flow with a login page. Whats pending is the first point: 
When the user open the application url from the windows machine in company network, he should get authenticated against the company LDAP server and be able to go the dashboard with being asked for password.