# Is there a bug with Spring Security In-Memory Configuration Feature?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I believe I have done all necessary setup for my Spring Security to work with Unicode, but it's not working with having special Unicode characters in the Username when using In-memory authentication.  As Spring claims to have internalisation support, could this be a bug with Spring Security In-Memory when using Unicode characters for usernames?  Be assured that I have looked up references manuals, forum posts (such as, [How to hold japanese characters in SPRING MVC POJO's field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062545/how-to-hold-japanese-characters-in-spring-mvc-pojos-field)), and have done all the things necessary for setup for Spring internationalisation. However, I am having problems the Spring Security 3 In-Memory username matching using Unicode/special characters.  Note, that my application, IDE and files uses UTF-8 and all appears well and all works well if I do **not** use special Unicode characters for Username.  I have a feeling that this non-matching of Unicode Usernames may be a bug with Spring Security In-Memory internalisation, but need this confirmed or if I have overseen anything, please let me know?

My snippets are as follows...

web.xml

```
      <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>encoding</param-name>
          <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
```

spring-servlet-context.xml

```
        <default-servlet-handler />

        <interceptors>      
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
            </beans:bean>

            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
                <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
            </beans:bean>   

        </interceptors> 


          <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


        <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
            <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
            <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Theme setup --> 
        <beans:bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
                <beans:property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
            <beans:property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
        </beans:bean>


        <beans:import resource="spring-security.xml"/>

         <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.platform" />

    </beans:beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
      <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />              


      <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">                
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />                      
        </authentication-provider> 
      </authentication-manager>

      <beans:import resource="user-security-bean-config.xml"/>
```

user-security-bean-config.xml

```
        <user-service id="userService">
          <user name="ışığı" password="encodedpasswordstring" 
                         authorities="R_U,R_A"/>

        </user-service>
```

Note, if I have user name as, for example, isigi (without special unicode characters), then all works well.

In my jsp files, I have at the top line:

```
<%@ page language="java" session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

... and in the *head* section, I have...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

And my xml files, UTF-8 declared at the top line, e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

No exceptions or errors are thrown.

Comment: As it is XML shouldn't you be encoding the username when using special characters? This is what (or at least should) happens when you are posting special characters through the web.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have entered the Unicode directly from the keyboard as in `<user name="cemış" ...` and I have also used the Unicode directly as in `<user name="cem&#x131;&#x15F;" ...` and still no success.  And this xml file is also save as UTF-8 and at the top line it also has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @M.Deinum By the way, I have in addition to entering Hexadecimal codes (above) for special characters **ı** and **ş**, also tried putting Unicode codes that match the same characters, that is, `<user name="cem\u0131\u015F" ...`, but still no success.  I have run out of ideas, which leads me to think could there be a bug with Spring Security In-memory when using special international Unicode characters? Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Then it would be a Java bug and not so much a Spring Security bug. In memory uses a `HashMap` for storage. My bet would be on the supplied data from the web (which for some reason might not be properly encoded).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for trying to help out, but after 2 days of trying to solve this problem, it turned out to be my web.xml configuration.

Comment: I really should have left my initial comment as is (I initially wanted to include a remark about filter ordering :) ). But glad that it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others who may experience similar problems, the **ORDER** of the *encodingFilter* in the web.xml file is very important and it must be at the **top** of the filter list otherwise it will not work.  Even though I have read the link that I posted, somehow I missed it twice, until I read the third late last night.  I forgot to mention in my post that I had correctly configured Tomcat settings to UTF-8 in the server.xml file by adding **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** in the appropriate places as follows:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>


<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```