# Special character with Spring authentication

Tags: java, spring, apache, http, authentication

I use the below code where I set credentials for basic http authentication to my server that uses Spring Security. 
Unfortunately I have problem with special characters like é,ò etc... I receive on server the question mark instead of correct character
Someone know how to resolve it? I've been finding to set encoding without success

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class RestClient extends RestTemplate { 
   public RestClient(String username, String password) {
         CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
         credsProvider.setCredentials(
                 new AuthScope(null, -1),
                 new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
         HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
         setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
        }
    }
```

Then I call web service with spring class:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(username, password);
response = restClient.getForObject(addQueryParam(url, queryParams), Response.class);
```

***UPDATE:***

Using this code I have the same error (question mark instead of special character). Some idea?

```
public class RestClient extends RestTemplate {
    private static RestClient instance;

    private RestClient(String username, String password) {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
        setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }

    public static synchronized RestClient getInstance(String username, String password){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new RestClient(username, password);
            instance.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
        return instance;

    }  
}
```

Comment: "Unfortunately I have problem with special characters like é,ò etc". Ok, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I receive on server question mark instead of correct character

Answer (score 0):

> Go to your web.xml and set the URIEncoding to UTF-8

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>


<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247135/is-there-a-bug-with-spring-security-in-memory-configuration-feature)

Comment: On the server or on the client? Because login from form page works

Comment: Change the web.xml (service side)

Comment: But are you refering to Tomcat configuration file? In spring I'm using java annotation

Answer (score 0):

You should add the right message converter
In my case when I had a similar issue I used this configuration:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
rt.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

After this all worked pretty good

Angelo

Comment: What I usually do is: to define a spring bean (singleton scope or, if you need, another kind of spring scope; in my scenarios singleton was sufficient) and then inject this bean whatever needed. But the first step I suggest to you is to test if this configuration works for you :)

Comment: may you post how you updated the class and what is the response you got?

Comment: so for example instead of 'à' you got '?' Am I right? If so this doesn't seem something related to spring. Try to set to TRACE the logging also for httpclient so you can see what is tranferred from server to client

Comment: both client and server use spring. Client send the right user and password but on the server I receive the question mark as you say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147136/discussion-between-angelo-immediata-and-luca).